# EKEventStore saveEvent:span:error: method return "nothing"

Tags: save, break, ekeventstore

This problem have spent me two days and I still have no clue to solve it.
I want to save some event to my calendar and the code is like the following:

```
+(BOOL)addEvent

    ... (create event) ...

    BOOL result = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents error:&error];

    if (result) {
        NSLog(@"Save Success");

        return YES;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error saving event: %@", error);
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Sometimes it works just fine, but sometimes the program will magically break after "saveEvent:..." method and neither "Save Success" nor "Error saving event" was printed on my console. I don't know how to trace the Error message. Can anyone tell me what I can do or what happen here? Thanks!

FYI: I'm using Xcode 5.1 and IOS simulator 7.0,7.1, device ipad,iphone IOS 7.1

Comment: The program didn't crash, it can still work like nothing happens, but my event didn't save into my calendar.

Comment: I had the same issue with Xcode6 - Swift. The solution was to restart device. :)